# calculating maximum volume size of fat 32 and HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fat32

I am trying to calculate the max volume and file size for fat 32 and hdfs.  for fat32 i have 4096 bytes sector size and 2^32 possible sectors . so 2^32 * 4096 = 1.759218604×10¹³ bytes or 17.6TB for the Volume size. But this should be 16TB according to the texts.

The same for HDFS: i have a block size (sector size) of 64mb and 63 bits to index the sectors and I do the same calculation : 2^63 * 64 = 590.29 YB . But this should equal 512 YB according to the texts  .  YB = Yota bytes  = 10^12TB

Comment: Not sure how this is a programming question

Comment: programmers might need to know this .. java + hadoop .

Comment: File sizes and disk blocks have noting to do with Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got your "according to the texts" from. Max volume size for a FAT32 file system is 32 GB for Windows 2000 and 127.53 GB for Windows 98 ([Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938432.aspx))

You also need to be careful with your byte calculations. Make sure you know if the texts you are referring to are using 2^n or 10^n for their reporting. 1 Terabyte (TB) = 10^12 bytes and 1 Tibibyte (TiB) = 2^40 bytes. So, 2^32 * 2^12 (4096) = 2^44 = 16 * 2^40 = 16 TiB.

Similarly, 2^63 * 2^6 (64) = 2^69 = 2^9 * 2^60 = 512 EiB

Your calculation of 590.29 YB is not correct... it works out to EB not YB. 1 EB = 10^18 bytes and 1 YB = 10^24 bytes

It's also worth noting that a lot times TB is used as short hand for TiB.